# get last element with linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this:

```
var result = (from t in MyDC
              where t.UserID == 6
              orderby t.UpdateTime
              select t.ID).Last();
```

Basically, I'm using Linq-to-Sql and it doesn't support the .Last operator. I could retrieve all the records of the user and then using linq to objects to get my value but I'm wondering how to do this with linq-to-sql and return only one record.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If you're looking for the "most recent update", could you use the linq .Max operator? Might be faster than ordering the entire set of records. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386972.aspx

Comment: @Rob, an order by clause does not result in "ordering the entire set of records".  It's still evaluated lazily such that getting the first row of an order by would cost no more than a `max`.

Comment: @KirkWoll - Interesting - I didn't know that.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just order by descending and use `.First()` instead:

```
var result = (from t in MyDC  
          where t.UserID == 6
          orderby t.UpdateTime descending
          select t.ID).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what you are sorting by, you could also use .Skip() and .Take() to reduce number of rows being returned